# Adding To Sidebar Makes Padded Footer Area Move to Right

Tags: html, css, tumblr, sidebar

I'm new at theme building and teaching myself, I hope I can explain myself properly:
When I add things to my tumblr sidebar, my expanded footer moves to the bottom of the sidebar. On my previous theme using:

```
<!--{/block:IfSidebar}-->
</div>
```

stopped this. On this one it does nothing as there is no call to action to start the sidebar that I can see, it's not negotiable.
I am using a heavily customized theme from a company who no longer provide theme support and updates, I'm using it as a template.
I know there is a simple answer to this, what am I missing?
http://thecomicartblog.tumblr.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Is it possible to see the theme with the issue in hand? From the comments above I can't quiet see the issue (Sidebar is at the side, footer is at the bottom).

Comment: I can take some screenshots, obviously it's fine at the moment but when I add anything else, that's when it goes screwy. Let me find a way to show you & I'll get back to you, thanks for offering to take a look!

Comment: I don't have enough contributions to add images,basically this: http://i.imgur.com/7jp434r.jpg leads to this: http://i.imgur.com/Um40RYY.jpg I am aware there is a lot of crap need strippinng from the original theme and I'm working on that but I just need to fix this first        <br /> is one thing that causes it or adding any dividers also causes the same problem. I'm stuck

Comment: It seems your fine adding anything to `#right_div'. Anything that goes inside, I would apply the following to: `float: left; width:100%;` I would also suggest using `margin-bottom` instead of `<br>`

Comment: Thanks so much, that seems to be working! I really like your theme portfolio btw, great work!

Comment: No problem, I really like your blog :D